# If statement omits a condition

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program in C that takes in any date and returns the zodiac sign.I have a function that is supposed to validate if the date is possible (day >0,month>0, if month ==x ,day <31 etc ) Thing is that on the part where it is supposed to validate the month and determine if it is a 30 month or a 31 month it only accepts one part of the conditions making it either a definite 30 day for all months or a 31 day for all months.
the function name is `fnValidacion()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
Programa : Signo Zodiaco.
Autor    : Samir Fersobe 1063021
Fecha    : Marzo 28, 2015
*/
const char *signo[12] = {"Aries","Tauro","Geminis","Cancer","Leo","Virgo","Libra","Escorpio",
                        "Sagitario","Capricornio","Acuario","Piscis"};//Arreglo de Signos Zodiacales


int Ano,Mes,Dia   ;//Variables de Ano , Mes y Dia.
int aprovacion = 0;//Determina si la funcion sigue o no.
int bisiesto = 1  ;//determina si el año es bisiesto.
int type          ;//determina la estacion.
//Funciones
void fnFecha()     ;//Consigue la fecha
void fnBisiesto()  ;//Define si el año es bisiesto.
void fnValidacion();//Determina si la fecha es valida.
void fnSigno()     ;//Determina el signo zodiacal.
void fnDevuelta()  ;//Devuelve la respuesta.
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fnFecha();
    fnBisiesto();
    fnValidacion();
    fnSigno();
    fnDevuelta();

}
void fnDevuelta()
{/*determinar si la funcion sigue o no, y devuelve el resultado al usuario */
    switch (aprovacion){
        case 1:
            printf("El Signo Zodiacal es %s",signo[type]);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n Intente de nuevo con otra fecha.");
            break;
                       }
}
void fnSigno()
{/*Determina el signo zodiacal*/
    switch(Mes){
            case 12:
                if (Dia < 22)
                    type = 8;
                else
                    type = 9;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (Dia < 20)
                    type = 9;
                else
                    type = 10;
                break;
            case 2:
                 if (Dia < 18)
                    type = 10;
                else
                    type = 11;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (Dia < 20)
                    type = 11;
                else
                    type = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                 if (Dia < 20)
                    type = 0;
                else
                    type = 1;
                break;
            case 5:
                 if (Dia < 21)
                    type = 1;
                else
                    type = 2;
                break;

            case 6:
                if (Dia < 21)
                    type = 2;
                else
                    type = 3;
                break;
            case 7:
                if (Dia < 23)
                    type = 3;
                else
                    type = 4;
                break;
            case 8:
                if (Dia < 28)
                    type = 4;
                else
                    type = 5;
                break;
            case 9:
                if (Dia < 23)
                    type = 5;
                else
                    type = 6;
                break;
            case 10:
                if (Dia < 23)
                    type = 6;
                else
                    type = 7;
                break;
            case 11:
                if (Dia < 22)
                    type = 7;
                else
                    type = 8;
                break;

    }
}
void fnBisiesto()
{/*determina si el ano es bisiesto */
    if ((Ano%4 != 0) || ((Ano%100 == 0) && (Ano%400 != 0)))
        bisiesto = 0;
}
void fnValidacion()
{/*Esta parte determina si la fecha es valida*/
    if  (
        (Ano < 0) || (Dia <0) || (Mes < 1) || (Mes > 12)  ||//Ano,Dia,Mes No negativo.Mes entre 1 y 12.
        (Dia > 31) || ((Mes == 4,6,9,11) && (Dia > 30))   ||//Dia no mayor que 31.Si mes es de 30, Dia no mayor que 30.
        ((bisiesto == 0) && (Mes == 2) && (Dia > 28))     ||//Si no es bisiesto febrero no mayor que 28.
        ((bisiesto == 1) && (Mes == 2) && (Dia > 29))       //Si es bisiesto febrero no mayor que 29.
        )
        printf("Esta fecha no es Valida.");                 //Explica al usuario que fecha no es valida.
    else
        return aprovacion = 1;
}
void fnFecha()
{/*Adquiere la fecha del usuario */
    printf("Inserte el Ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &Ano);
    printf("Inserte el Mes: ");
    scanf("%d", &Mes);
    printf("Inserte el Dia: ");
    scanf("%d", &Dia);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Point 1. Please learn to  provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___. Point 2) Please use english language in sample code to help uderstand better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, your problem is in

```
(Mes == 4,6,9,11)
```

You have to write all the conditions individually, maybe something like

```
((Mes == 4) || (Mes == 6) || (Mes == 9) || (Mes ==11))
```

Otherwise, as per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence),  your code will look like

```
 ((Mes == 4), 6,9,11)
```

where `(Mes == 4)` producing either `0` or `1`. Next, as per the `,` operator property, <sup><#></sup>

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

So, finally, your expression becomes `(11)`, which is a `true` value for `if` condition or logical operator.

---

<sub>[@Quoted from `C11` standard, chapter `§6.5.17`]</sub>.

Comment: So basically I should make it like a switch style?

Comment: @Samir if you prefer, yes.

Comment: @ryancdotnet Please, atleast post like [this](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#auto/en/Buena%20respuesta). :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza it worked , thing is you cant do this (mes == 4,3,2) no work for multiple values and do the validation.

Comment: @Samir Yes, my point is that you don't understand *why*, nor what `mes = 4,3,2` means.

Comment: You can link... [C11 (n1570), §6.5.17](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.17)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Thank you, but I'm behind a _protected_ (sigh !) network and can't access the link. _maybe_ many more, too. :-(